# Correct Way to bind ComboBox to CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

Hey i have a CollectionViewSource Property on my ViewModel.

This ViewModel is bound to a ComboBox this way:

```
<ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Products.View}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity.Product}"  
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

When binding to an existing SelectedEntity it works fine.

When i try to bind to an `SelectedEntity`, that dosn't posses a Product i want to display the first Item from the List. Therefore i tried to use `Products.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()`, but still the first item isn't displayed.

It of course works when i set `SelectedEntity.Product = Products.View.CurrentItem.`

What can i do, to improve my code? This looks somewhat wrong to me...

Comment: Need some more info:
"doesn't possess a product" - does that mean the Product is null or that the Product property doesn't exist?  Or either?
Where are you calling MoveCurrentToFirst?
Where are you calling the assignment to CurrentItem?

Comment: The Product is null. I call the assignment in the constructor of my ViewModel

Comment: CollectionViewSource can be defined in xaml, and bound to a collection on your ViewModel, then you can bind the ItemsSource of your ItemsControl (your ComboBox) to the CollectionViewSource. CollectionViewSource is a part of the view.

Comment: Why do you need to bind to SelectedItem anyway?
You could listen to changes in the current item from the view,
e.g. Products.View.CurrentChanged += YourHandler
if you need to handle a selection change.
Otherwise if your SelectedEntity changes (whatever it is) you can
then with Products.View.MoveCurrentTo(object) set the selected item in the combobox.
I think the reason why your call to MoveCurrentToFirst isn't working is that you bound the SelectedItem property of the combobox, preventing the selected item change.

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem I think is mainly there for binding an ItemsSource to an ICollectionView (which you are doing) and then you can listen to changes of the current item in the ICollectionView with adding an eventhandler to ICollectionView.CurrentChanged/CurrentChanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedItem in WPF selects the entire instance, so if you're binding SelectedItem to an Entity's navigation property, then all is good.  However, if you're binding SelectedItem to an Entity's non-navigation property, then this can be a problem, and I'd recommend if this this a business requirement that you instead bind SelectedValue.

For me, I find it best to bind SelectedItem to my Entity's navigation property AND SelectedValue to my Entity's value property.

I hope this helps.